How to compute the dimension of subspace fixed by a a group action?
If $G$ is a compact group acting linearly on a Hilbert space $V$, the set
$$
\{
x \in V \mid g \cdot x = x, \ \forall g \in G
\}
$$
is a vector space.
Are there methods to determine its dimension if we assume that we can represent $V$ as a direct sum of known irreducible representations of $G$?
